# How to get App ID for an existing facebook page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-comments

I have the following case:

My client already has a facebook page with timeline and a decent amount of likes.
My job is to integrate facebook comments and facebook like to their website. For this I need an App ID, which I can easily get by creating a new app on developers.facebook.com

What I want is to somehow connect this app to the client's page so;

- it shows up on their insights report
- maybe likes and interactions get connected to the client's page instead of an app

I have already spent many hours trying to get this to work, but I don't yet see a way. 
I can imagine that when I create a new App and then add a page to that app I have them connected. Though my client's company isn't an "app", it's a real-world business. Also, this way my clients loses all their likes on their current page.

Please help me figuring out the right way to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use graph API to get id of a page like this: https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=http://facebook.com/samplepage

Comment: This is only applicable to pages though! i tried it with groups and apps...but haven't found anything yet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no way to link an existing app and page (by 'link' i mean mark the page as being the page which represents that app) - you can of course install an app on to your page as a tab, or use an app to manage the page and post updates, etc, the documentation for both of which is on the main developer site

Comment: The only reason I'm creating an "app" is to be able to use facebook comments on the website. Would you happen to know if there is another way to connect the facebook comments to a page? Or to even moderate comments without an app id?

Comment: You can moderate the comments via the admin interface, visible to the users whose uids are in the 'fb:admins' tag on the page

Comment: Ah, I see now. Allthough I can't seem to log on to developers.facebook.com/tools/comments without an app id. Man using FB can be tiresome. Thank you very much for your quick help though. Guess we'll just have to live with it :)

Answer (score 10):

If you have a Pretty URL, you can go to http://graph.facebook.com/{yourpagename}.  The App ID of the page will be right there at the top.  If you do NOT have a Pretty URL for the page, the App ID of the page is the number at the very end of its URL.

Comment: It returns an error:
`"An access token is required to request this resource."`

Comment: Unfortunately FB has removed unauthenticated access to the Graph API for Pages.  You'll need to create an application at http://developers.facebook.com and use its ID instead.

Comment: Ahh nice Justin, figured that was the case.

Comment: I can get what looks like an app ID from a page via the graph method given here, but when used in the fb:app_id tag on a page, the [Facebook sharing debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/) warns that it is not a valid app ID.

Answer (score 0):

Login to your page >> Click on Settings > Click on Apps from left panel > Select your page app >> Go to the bottom
Here you can find User ID

Comment: There no longer is an Apps section in the left panel, at least not for our page.